# Getting XML node matching XPath expression

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing

I'm hoping you can help with this.  I tried a number of XPath testers online and wasn't able to find a solution.

I'm trying to get the value of the first node with the '~tid' attribute from this XML:

```
<Response status="ok" version="1.1">
                 <Action>
                    <Page>
                       <Params>
                          <Param name="~tid" value="1345811517165"/>
                          <Param name="~action-type" value="DATA"/>
                          <Param name="~from-page" value="login"/>
                          <Param name="~from-act" value="submitData"/>
                          <Param name="login_USERNAME" value="" type="0"/>
                          <Param name="login_PASSWORD" value="" type="0"/>
                       </Params>
                    </Page>
                    <Data name="clientData" method="POST">
                       <Params>
                          <Param name="timezoneoffset" value=""/>
                          <Param name="daylightsavings" value=""/>
                       </Params>
                    </Data>
                 </Action>
                 <Action>
                    <Page>
                       <Params>
                          <Param name="~tid" value="1345811517165"/>
                          <Param name="~action-type" value="NAV"/>
                          <Param name="~from-page" value="login"/>
                          <Param name="~from-act" value="resetPassword"/>
                          <Param name="~to-page" value="login_resetPassword"/>
                       </Params>
                    </Page>
                 </Action>
                 <Action>
                    <Page>
                       <Params>
                          <Param name="~tid" value="1345811517165"/>
                          <Param name="~action-type" value="NAV"/>
                          <Param name="~from-page" value="login"/>
                          <Param name="~from-act" value="newUser"/>
                          <Param name="~to-page" value="login_newUser"/>
                       </Params>
                    </Page>
                 </Action>
</Response>
```

The XPath I'm using is:

```
//Params[1]/Param[@name='~tid']/@value
```

It gets all three values.  How can I get just the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
/descendant::Params[1]/Param[@name='~tid']/@value
```

From the [W3C XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

> **NOTE:** The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are the first `para` children of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the second most FAQ in XPath**.

**Use**:

```
(//Params/Param[@name='~tid'])[1]/@value
```

**Or even**:

```
(//Param[@name='~tid'])[1]/@value
```

**Explanation**:

The XPath pseudo-operator `//` has lower precedence (priority) than the `[]` operator.

The usual solution in any laguage when default priority needs to be overriden is to use brackets that explicitly specify the new, wanted priorities.